# WebSphere 9 ND node agent stopped and the applications are still working. How/why?

Tags: authentication, communication, status, agent, websphere-9

This is WebSphere 9 ND. I've stopped the node agent and the serverStatus.sh script reports that it is down:  ADMU0509I: The Node Agent "nodeagent" cannot be reached. Why are the applications still authenticating and appear to be working?

Answer (score 1):

See this [article](https://help.hcltechsw.com/sametime/10.0/plan/plan_was_glossary.html) explaining the basic concepts of IBM Websphere application server Network Deployment.

> **node agent**
> A node agent manages all managed processes on a WebSphere Application Server on a node by communicating with the Network Deployment Manager to coordinate and synchronize the configuration. A node agent performs management operations on behalf of the Network Deployment Manager. The node agent represents the node in the management cell. Node agents are installed with WebSphere Application Server base, but are not required until the node is added to a cell in a Network Deployment environment.
>
> **application server**
> The application server is the primary component of WebSphere. The server runs a Java™ virtual machine, providing the runtime environment for the application's code. The application server provides containers that specialize in enabling the execution of specific Java application components.

Apps are deployed into the Application server and not to the nodeagent. The role of the node agent is to perform management operations on behalf of Deployment Manager.

So, if the nodeagent is stopped, you will only loose the ability to manage the servers running under that node and it will not stop already running application
servers or applications deployed to servers in that node.

You can validate this by grepping the server name (eg:server1) from the list of all running processes:

```
 ps -ef | grep java | grep servername
```

Sample output (for an app server) is given below:

```
wasadmin  12345 98765  2 13:18 pts/0    00:04:57 /opt/ibm/WebSphere/AppServer/java/8.0/bin/java -Dosgi.install.area=/opt/ibm/WebSphere/AppServer <collapsed text> cellname nodename servername
```

where:

- **wasadmin** - is the os username running the application server on that
  node
- **12345** - is the pid of the application server running on that node.
- **98765** - is the pid of the parent process (nodeagent). This will be
  "1" if the nodeagent is stopped